# Given that $p, p+1$ and $2p+1$ are prime numbers, find sum of all possible values of $p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given that $p, p+1$ and $2p+1$ are prime numbers, find sum of all possible values of $p$.
According to me $p$ can have only one value, i.e. $2$.
This is because $p$ and $p+1$ are consecutive primes and only two consecutive primes exist, $2$ and $3$. So, $p=2$ and sum of all values of $p$ should also be $2$.

Now, the book in which I find the problem gives 5 as answer.(Q51)[image: book photo]Here is the answer Key.[image] So, who is correct?

If the book is correct then how?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133746/discussion-on-question-by-spideycoding25-given-that-p-p1-and-2p1-are-prim).

Comment: Your argument is correct by the linked dupe. It's best to delete questions based on misprints/typos/brainos since they have no lasting value and only serve to obscure search results (closing comment migrated from chatified comments - cf. link above).

Comment: The misprint is obviously in the text of the problem. It should be $2p-1$ instead of $p+1$. Then the problem makes sense and the answer "$5$" is correct.
I would advise you to change the title and body of the question to be aimed on the search of the misprint (error) in the book.